# Difficulty interpreting bounding volumes from Google 3D Tiles API

Tags: tiles, extents, google-earth, google-maps-api, 3d-map

I'm trying to create my own 3D globe, similar to Google Earth, by getting the relevant tile data from the Google Tiles API.

Using several steps to load the relevant data from Google, I receive a json file with a tile hierarchy, starting at root object with several children, which represent 1/8 subdivisions of the Earth, and subdiving further for every child in the hierarchy.

Part of this data is something called a "boundingVolume" - which every object has - consisting of 12 double precision floating point values. The issue I am facing now is on how to interpret the values of this boundingVolume.

My initial theory was that the 12 values represent a set of 4 vectors that specify a position, and 3 half-extents (OBB) in ECEF coordinates, but this might not be the right approach, as when I visualize this "volume" the shape is very irregular and does not seem entirely logical.

What I can say I got correct is the first 3 values or "center", as cross-referencing the downloaded tile in question with the visuals of the corresponding ECEF coordinates on Google Earth seems to point to it being the correct location. The other 9 values remain a mystery, however.

One set of values I tested is the following:

```
[2118175.985704, -5087054.161776937, -2329068.2868234566, 5072935.755414925, -2101829.4301545424, -2329050.4687001207, 1709546.129977461, 1747924.9776337112, -5477895.268053877, 5103363.602095115, 2101837.3370224303, -2329059.027032251]
```

Another theory I have is that the values may represent the sides of some shape, as some of the values are relatively close in absolute value but have different signs. If this is anything relevant, I'm unsure of, though.

Does anyone have any experience with this stuff or any recommendations?

Comment: did you figure this out?